# Wso2 apiman: INVALID REQUEST, invalid_callback

Tags: ssl, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I want to start the apimanger in my windows laptop, and access it with a custom url

From logs, it looks like I have to replace "localhost"

**wso2carbon.log**

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-02-29 14:06:47,948]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.core.PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through HTTP Listener started on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8280
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-02-29 14:06:47,950]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpMultiSSLListener} - Starting Pass-through HTTPS Listener...
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-02-29 14:06:47,960]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.core.PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through HTTPS Listener started on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8243
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-02-29 14:06:48,516]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.service.impl.TaskServiceImpl} - Task service starting in STANDALONE mode...
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-02-29 14:06:48,588]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.eventing.internal.RegistryEventingServiceComponent} - Successfully Initialized Eventing on Registry
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-02-29 14:06:49,021]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.JMXServerManager} - JMX Service URL  : service:jmx:rmi://localhost:11111/jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-02-29 14:06:49,027]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Server           :  WSO2 API Manager-3.0.0
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-02-29 14:06:49,029]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - WSO2 Carbon started in 216 sec
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-02-29 14:06:50,175]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} - Mgt Console URL  : https://<host>:9443/carbon/
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-02-29 14:06:50,177]  INFO
```

What config changes need to be made?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaroud

Go to this url:

https://yourhost:9443/carbon/oauth/edit.jsp?appName=admin_admin_publisher

Replace this regexp in callback uri that has localhost:

regexp=(https://**localhost**:9443/publisher/services/auth/callback/login|https://**localhost**:9443/publisher/services/auth/callback/logout)

Corrected regexp:

regexp=(https://yourhost:9443/publisher/services/auth/callback/login|https://yourhost:9443/publisher/services/auth/callback/logout)

I hope wso2 fixes this so we don't need to hack:

[image]

I'm able to get to /devportal