# WSO2 3 : Error while generating PRODUCTION token for application

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I was able to get past invalid_callback error. Ref: [Wso2 apiman: INVALID REQUEST, invalid_callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60468854/wso2-apiman-3-0-0-error-invalid-request-invalid-callback/60471699#60471699)

**However, I'm not able to generate tokens for api.** Any workaround is much appreciated.

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.**SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: localhost != dev.org**

2020-03-01T12:06:46,418 [-] [https-jsse-nio-9443-exec-40] ERROR APIConsumerImpl Error while re-generating AccessToken
org.wso2.**carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException**: Error while creating tokens - hostname in certificate didn't match: localhost != dev.org

**Any other changes to be made?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround for "Error generating PRODUCTION token" is :

1. Un-comment section [apim.oauth_config] '**revoke_endpoint**' lines as
   shown below.
2. Replace

Change this : revoke_endpoint = "https://**localhost**:${https.nio.port}/revoke"

To :revoke_endpoint = "https://**dev.apigw.org**:${https.nio.port}/revoke"

```
[apim.oauth_config]
#enable_outbound_auth_header = false
#auth_header = "Authorization"
revoke_endpoint = "https://dev.apigw.org:${https.nio.port}/revoke"
#enable_token_encryption = false
#enable_token_hashing = false
```

Comment: The error is "localhost != dev.apigw.org" ... if it is a certificate issue, the error would be " dev.apigw.org != localhost" ..  The certificate I generated already has CN=dev.apigw.org, so not a certificate issue.

Comment: Is this a single node setup?

Comment: Yes single node,  in my windows laptop. The changes I made in config files are in the link at the top of this post.

Comment: Please add the below configuration as well to deployment.toml file.
[apim.oauth_config]
revoke_endpoint = "https://dev.apigw.org:${https.nio.port}/revoke"

Comment: Menaka, Replaced your initial answer about 'certificate issue', with your solution on [apim.oauth_config], and accepted this answer -- The change worked for me. It is a revoke_endpoint config issue. I hope  the next release of apim takes the hostname="dev.apigw.org" from deployment.toml, plugsin/enables/interpolates the section  [apim.oauth_config].

Answer (score 1):

One other approach you can follow is adding `localhost` as a `SAN` when you generate the new certificate/keystore.